# get User Name from user.id

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Is it possible to get User Name from user.id file using native Notes/Domino capabilities: LotusScript, Java, C API etc?

I need to import thousands id files from local folder into database and one of wish is to set user name for each id-document.

So far I do it in a bit ugly way (but that works), I simply read content of user.id file (using NotesStream) and try to find a match with

```
CN=**********/O=
```

I noticed that user name is written few times in user.id file and server name (I guess where id was registered) is only once, that helps me to find user name, but that is of course not a solid solution, but rather a backup plan.